Involution centralizers in $\mathrm{PCSO}^{+}(8,3)$
According to Table 4.5.1 of [1], there should be 10 classes of involutions of type "p" and "e" in $\operatorname{Aut}(K)$ where $K=K_a=P\Omega^{+}(8,3)$.
And Table 4.5.1 also gives the centralizer structure of each involution class in $\operatorname{Inndiag}(K)$. I understand that here $\operatorname{Inndiag}(K)=\operatorname{PCSO}^{+}(8,3)$ where $\operatorname{CSO}^{+}(8,3)$ is the conformal special orthogonal group.
My reading of Table 4.5.1 for the centralizer structure:
$$\begin{array}{cc}
\text{class} & \text{order} \\
\Omega^{+}(6,3).2.2.2 & 48522240 \\
\Omega^{-}(6,3).4.2^2.2 & 209018880 \\
\Omega^{+}(4,3)^2/2.2.(2^2\times 2).2^2 & 2654208 \\
\Omega^{-}(4,3)^2.2.(2^2\times 2).2^2 & 8294400 \\
\text{$P\Omega^{+}(4,9).2.2.2^2$ (two copies)} & 2073600 \\
\text{$\operatorname{SL}(4,3)/2.2.2.2$ (two copies)} & 48522240 \\
\text{$\operatorname{SU}(4,3)/2.4.4.2$ (two copies)} & 209018880
\end{array}$$
Note that the second to last component is the group "Outdiag", to use the notation of [1].
I did some computation using Magma in $\operatorname{PCSO}^{+}(8,3)$. There are 10 classes of involution indeed. But the centralizer orders don't match completely. Which part of my understanding is not correct?
[1] Gorenstein, Daniel, Richard Lyons, and Ronald Solomon. Classification of the Finite Simple Groups, Number 3. 1st ed. Vol. 40. Providence: American Mathematical Society, 1997. Print.
Edit:
Computation results:
involution centralizers and their orders
[ C4.2A(3,3).D4, C4.2A(3,3).D4, C4.2A(3,3).D4, C2*PSL(4,3).C2^2, C2*PSL(4,3).C2^2, C2*PSL(4,3).C2^2, C2.A6^2.C2^3, C2.A6^2.C2^3, C2.A6^2.C2^3, C2.C2^8.C3^4.C2.C2^4 ]

[ 104509440, 104509440, 104509440, 48522240, 48522240, 48522240, 2073600, 2073600, 2073600, 1327104 ]


It seems hard to answer the question without knowing your results.  Could you summarise them?

Yes, yes. Do you mean the computation results? thank you

Re, yes, if you have specific expected results and actual results, then it would probably help to post them.

OK. I will post them.

Many thxs for the editing

I suspect that you have the wrong group. If G is the simple group then the multiplier of $G$ is $2\times 2$ while the outer automorphism group is $S_4$. The outer automorphisms act on the $2\times 2$ through the quotient $S_3$. So any particular double cover of $G$ has fewer automorphisms than $G$. And even the double covers that admit involutary automorphisms don't necessarily fit together to make a group of the form $2.G.2$. So my suspicion is that the group is twice as big as you think, but without a lot of work trying to reconcile your notation with GLS, it's hard to comment further.

OK. Thanks. Do you mean the Inndiag is wrong or the centralizers?

I guess I mean your Inndiag could be wrong. It's only a guess.
